# Finding k in a pmf problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been given a homework problem similar to this one:

```
Consider the following pmf: 

p(x)= 1/k^2 for x=1,2,3,4,5,6

Determine the value of k
```

I've gone over every pmf problem in my book but none of them have been formatted this way. I would understand if the question was p(x) = 1/x^2 but I don't understand where the k is coming from or what it represents. Would anyone be willing to offer some insight on how I might solve this problem?

Comment: You need to find $k$ such that $\sum_{x=1}^6 1/k^2 =1$. Here $k$ is the normalization constant and $p(x)$ is constant in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$ is a constant which has to be determined such that $p(x)$ is a probability mass function. The idea behind the exercise probably is that you learn that one has to normalize $p$. You know that one therefore has to have

$$\sum_{x = 1}^6 p(x) = 1.$$

Here, we have the special case $p(x) \equiv 1/k^2$ for all $x$, i. e., $p$ is constant. So we have

$$\sum_{x = 1}^6 p(x) = \sum_{x = 1}^6 \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{k^2} \sum_{x = 1}^6 1 = \frac{6}{k^2} \stackrel{!}{=} 1.$$

This equation has the real solutions $k = \pm \sqrt{6}$. But we know that $p(x)$ has to be in $[0, 1]$, for which we have to discard the negative solution and obtain $k = \sqrt{6}$.